# bool return value in function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering why the below function template specialization does not compile
(due to `no return statement in function returning non-void`).

```
class Boring {
public:
    template<typename T> bool eval() const { }
};

template<> inline bool Boring::eval<int>() const { return true; }
```

I would expect that the non-specialized function template would not be evaluated unless used. If the return type is changed to `T*`, the below compiles successfully.

```
int x = 5;

class Boring {
public:
    template<typename T> T* eval() const { }
};

template<> inline int* Boring::eval<int>() const { return &x; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both programs are well-formed. Although undefined behaviour would occur if the primary `eval` template were instantiated and invoked, that does not render the program ill-formed. However, you have your compiler in some mode where it treats some warnings as errors (perhaps `-Wall`), or it treats this particular warning as an error by default.

Comment: I suppose my question comes from the fact that the primary eval template in the T* case would result in the same error (invalid return type), but the bool return case results in the compilation error. Both function templates have empty bodies.

Comment: @JohnKane That's a quality of implementation issue. File a bug against your compiler for not being able to detect the lack of return statement in the second case.